# DIV appear differently in chrome only

Tags: html, css

I have a website at [bgflirt.com](http://bgflirt.com) that appears differently in FireFox and Chrome. This is how it looks in firefox:
[image: ffdisplay] and here's how it looks in chrome:[image: chdisplay]

As you can see, in chrome (and safari) the page is not stretched to fit the entire screen. I'm using this code for positioning the div containing the flash on the right:

```
<div style="width: 200px; position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 10px; overflow: hidden;">
    </div>
```

The page should look the way it does in firefox, in all browsers. Any ideas on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some quick tinkering, I managed to fix it. Dont know what it will do with other browsers though:

```
#content_wrap {
  margin-left: 130px; //remove this
  //other styles
}
```

edit: Also tried on IE8, appears that `margin-left` is a superfluous style.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you do not have a zoom level set to lower than 100% in chrome

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to set your div#container to 100% width

```
div#container {
padding: 0px 0px;
width:100%;
 }
```